# There is no Calendar in the Emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I am building an application that accesses the Facebook account and gets the events then add them to Android Calendar.

There is no calendar in the emulator.

We tried to setup the Calendar.apk but it did not work.

Any idea?

I want to add events to the calendar through code directly. Is it possible or I have to add them to the online google calendar?

Any API?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Calendar is a part of Google Apps. And there's no GApps on emulator by default.
You can try [this](http://tech-droid.blogspot.com/2009/11/android-market-on-emulator.html) solution.
They're trying to get Android Market on their emulator, but I believe there's a Calendar and Mail and all other GApps all included in their OS image.

Comment: don't forget to put a green checkmark under my answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

I also needed calendar on adnroid emulator. The solution was next:

1. download Calendar.apk (native android calendar)
2. install it wia adb (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) with the command

   > adb -e install Calendar.apk