# Need support for calendar event

Tags: android

I am developing mobile app for job portal using android, in that i have list view , I have used image view in the list view date colomn  my requirement is to add calendar event automatically if i click the imageview. Below is the code I have used, after i run the application the emulator showing app closed unexpectedly, some times no response about the calendar event remaining all things works fine  . please suggest me thanks for the help.

```
Button btnLogin;
Button btnRegister;
Button btnsignUp;
ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
EditText etUserName;
EditText etPassword;

EditText etUserNameSignUp;
EditText etPasswordSignUp;
EditText etPhoneSignUp;

Button btnExit;
Button btnHome;
Button btnNotifications;
Button btnAvalability;
Button btnUpdate;

Button btnPublish;
Button btnStatus;
Button btnNotify;

String[] companies = new String[] { "Infosys", "Wipro", "Cisco", "ibm",
        "tcs", "NWS" };

int[] images = new int[] { R.drawable.notifications,
        R.drawable.notifications, R.drawable.notifications,
        R.drawable.notifications, R.drawable.notifications,
        R.drawable.notifications,

};

String[] dates = new String[] { "21/08/12", "22/08/12", "20/08/12",
        "16/08/12", "18/08/12", "24/08/12", };

String[] type = new String[] { "Face To Face", "Written", "Online",
        "telephonc", "group discussion", "telephonic" };






@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    userName.add("Raghu");
    password.add("Raghu");

    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.main);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnsignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
    btnsignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userEditText);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwEditText);

    etUserNameSignUp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regNameEditText);
    etPasswordSignUp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regEmailEditText);
    etPhoneSignUp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regPhEditText);

    btnHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
    btnHome.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitButton);
    btnExit.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnNotifications = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listButton);
    btnNotifications.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnAvalability = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rightButton);
    btnAvalability.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnPublish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.publishButton);
    btnPublish.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
    btnStatus.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnNotify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notificationButton);
    btnNotify.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Each row in the list stores company name, interview date,
    // notification icon and type of interview
    List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("cmp", companies[i]);
        hm.put("date", "   " + dates[i]);
        hm.put("img", Integer.toString(images[i]));
        hm.put("type", "   " + type[i]);
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "cmp", "date", "img", "type" };

    // Ids of views in lvrow.xml
    int[] to = { R.id.cmp, R.id.date, R.id.imgv, R.id.type };

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.lvrow.xml defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList,
            R.layout.listview, from, to);

    // Getting a reference to listview of listvi.xml layout file
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    /*listView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);*/

}

OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    // @Override
    // onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    // {
    // ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId)).getText();
    // // or do your stuff
    // }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        ImageView viewObj = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.imgv);
        viewObj.setImageResource(R.drawable.bgrighticon);

    }
};


private void readContent(String uriString) {

    Uri calendarUri;
    Uri eventUri;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7 )
    {
      //the old way
      calendarUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"); 
      eventUri    = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    }
    else
    {
     //the new way
     calendarUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
     eventUri    = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    } 

}

private void addEvent(){
    try {
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        event.put("calendar_id", "1");
        event.put("title", "tet event");
        event.put("description", "hello this is testing of event");
        event.put("eventLocation", "Ahmedabad");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long date = c.getTimeInMillis();
        event.put("dtstart", date);
        event.put("dtend", date);
        event.put("allDay", 1);
        event.put("eventStatus", 1);
        event.put("hasAlarm", 1);
        Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
        Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
        Log.e("uri", url.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == btnLogin) {
        if (userName.contains(etUserName.getText().toString())
                && password.contains(etPassword.getText().toString()))

        {
            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(3);

        } else {

        }

        loggedin = true;

    } else if (v == btnRegister) {
        viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(5);
    } else if (v == btnsignUp) {// reister new user
        // Take the values from the user entered data and save it in
        // Arraylist

    } else if (v == btnHome) {
        if (loggedin) {
            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(3);
        } else {
            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
        }

    } else if (v == btnExit) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (v == btnNotifications) {
        if (loggedin) {
            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(4);
        }
    } else if (v == btnAvalability) {
        if (loggedin) {
            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
        }
    } else if (v == btnUpdate) {
        if (loggedin) {
            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
        }
    }

    else if (v == btnPublish) {
        if (loggedin) {
            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
        }

    } else if (v == btnStatus) {
        if (loggedin) {
            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
        }

    } else if (v == btnNotify) {
        if (loggedin) {
            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(4);
        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Calendar is part of Google Apps so it is not available in emulator.

First way : test your application on android device having Google Calendar app installed in it.

Second way : install Google calendar app in your emulator and test your application in it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2927542/582571) will help you more.

Edit :

You can check that if application with specific package name is install or not

```
public boolean check()
{
    try{
        ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("packagename", 0 );
        return true;
    } catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi i have done what u said , i have tested in android device and i have installed local calendar in emulator but it is showing the same error "app stopped unexpectedly" please help me out.

Comment: did you test on device ?? is there error in logcat, if yes then pls post

Comment: yes i have tested on device the application running without adding any event to the calendar. no functionality happens regarding calendar.

Comment: check the google code project link in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12033867/582571, & test that sample app & find code as well.

Comment: Hi., rajpara, i have changed my code and tested in emulator , there is no such unexpected stoping of app , i need to check in the device once, is there any way to show calendar in emulator , because i do not have android device testing each and every time in my friends device is problem for me, thanks for ur support.

Comment: as i mention , you have to install google calendar application in your emulator

Comment: hi., i have installed google calendar but it is asking me to create an account , while creating account it is showing the connection to the server could not established . how can i rectify this one .